# the format of the output of gcc preprocesing

Tags: gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

I see the following output of gcc preprocessing. I don't find the documentation of the output format. Could anybody let me know what it is? Thanks.

```
$ cat a.h
#include "b.h"
$ cat b.h
#define X Y
$ gcc -E -dD - <<< '#include "a.h"'
...
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>" 2
# 1 "./a.h" 1
# 1 "./b.h" 1
#define X Y
# 2 "./a.h" 2
# 2 "<stdin>" 2
```

When I try the following, I see more numbers, which are different from the above. I am not sure about what they mean either.

```
$ gcc -E -dD - <<< '#include <sys/socket.h>'
...
# 19 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/posix_types_64.h" 2 3 4
# 8 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/posix_types.h" 2 3 4
# 37 "/usr/include/linux/posix_types.h" 2 3 4
# 6 "/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sockios.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/asm-generic/sockios.h" 1 3 4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Unusual lines are linemarkers, which specify linenumber and filename. Numbers after the filename are special flags.

These are explained in [GCC Preprocessor online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html#Preprocessor-Output):

> Source file name and line number information is conveyed by lines of
> the form
>
> `# linenum filename flags`
>
> These are called *linemarkers*. They are inserted as needed into the
> output (but never within a string or character constant). They mean
> that the following line originated in file *filename* at line *linenum*.
> *filename* will never contain any non-printing characters; they are
> replaced with octal escape sequences.
>
> After the file name comes zero or more flags, which are ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’,
> or ‘4’. If there are multiple flags, spaces separate them. Here is
> what the flags mean:
>
> ‘1’ This indicates the start of a new file.
> ‘2’ This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).
> ‘3’ This indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so certain warnings should be suppressed.
> ‘4’ This indicates that the following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit extern "C" block.